# iterating indexes of items in a list with a condition python

Tags: python

i would want to print out the indexes of the items that are 'H' but it is stuck in one item.

here's my code:

```
import random

def coinflipping():
    #generating 100 coin flips
    coins = []
    coin_sides = ['H', 'T']
    for i in range(100):
        coins.append(coin_sides[random.randint(0, 1)])
    return coins

sides = coinflipping()
print(sides)

for i in sides:
    if i == 'H':
        print(sides.index(i))
```

and here's the output:

[image: output]

Comment: Please provide the code as text not as images. This is easier to try out your code. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @hninsat Edit your question and add the relevant code to it - that way it'll be properly formatted and available in the question itself. Images and code in comments are bad for accessibility and making sense of the question for those who read it.

Comment: sorry im new to this, i just edited my question :0

Comment: @hninsat Please add your code to your question and suround it with 3 ` so everyone can read it easily.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way of doing it:

```
import random

def coinflipping():
    #generating 100 coin flips
    coins = []
    coin_sides = ['H', 'T']
    for i in range(100):
        coins.append(coin_sides[random.randint(0, 1)])
    return coins

sides = coinflipping()
print(sides)

for i,t in enumerate(sides):
    if t == 'H':
        print(i)
```

[image]

Remember that `index` returns the first occurrence of an item. And since `sides` are your static list it always returns `1` because `H` is first met in the index `1` in your `random` case.

You can check enumerate [here](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/).

Another way of doing it is this:

```
a = [np.random.choice(['H','T']) for x in range(100)]
result = [x[0] for x in enumerate(a) if x[1]=='H']

# returns a list of indexes where 'H' was flipped.
```

Answer (score 1):

not the best way to do that but it will work

```
import random

def coinflipping():
    #generating 100 coin flips
    coins = []
    coin_sides = ['H', 'T']
    for i in range(100):
        coins.append(coin_sides[random.randint(0, 1)])
    return coins

sides = coinflipping()
print(sides)
c = -1
for i in sides:
    c = c +1
    if i == 'H':
        print(c)
```

[image: like this : photo]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in range(len(sides)):
    if sides[i] == 'H':
        print(i)
```

Comment: `range(len(sides))` is number of trials, and of course it will be greater than number of sides, so `sides[i]` will give error.

Comment: Works perfectly with no error the range starts at 0 index starts at 0